# Translate WireGuard config from iptables to nft

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, wireguard, nftables

I was installing WireGuard on a fresh Raspberry Pi OS image and wanted to move the server config from another device onto this. But bringing up the interface said it can't find the `iptables` command. That's when I remembered that iptables was said to be obsolete. So it's time for some new tech again. ;-)

Problem is, I can't use it. My WireGuard server config has these lines, I guess to allow clients to connect to my entire home network.

```
[Interface]
PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

These networking tools change faster than I ever use them, so there's no point in learning one, really, because my knowledge will be useless next time.

So I installed the iptables package to get the new `iptables-translate` command I've read about. It converted the first line to this:

```
PostUp   = nft add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname "%i" counter accept; nft add rule ip filter FORWARD oifname "%i" counter accept; nft add rule ip nat POSTROUTING oifname "eth0" counter masquerade
```

Much longer now. Others may find it more readable. A test would show if it's equivalent. But the second line cannot be translated. So I'm stuck here. What should I write as the second line to bring the interface down again?

Or is there a better and simpler alternative to this configuration altogether?

(I know that I have iptables available on that system by now. But who knows how long it will remain in the repositories so I'd like to prepare now and convert my stuff to be a bit more future-proof.)

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a better and simpler alternative to this configuration altogether?

Yes, add the same rules to your static ruleset.

Netfilter doesn't actually require the interface to exist when using `-i` or `iifname`. Whether you're using iptables or nft, you can just keep the rule active all the time – when the interface exists it'll work; when the interface doesn't exist it'll do nothing at all.

> These networking tools change faster than I ever use them, so there's no point in learning one, really

The last change in Linux firewall tools (ipchains to iptables) happened approximately 20 years ago.

The current version of the `iptables` command has been rewritten to use the nft backend. (Most distributions have packages for both variants, but if you have iptables-translate, then most likely you also have the nft-based iptables version.) This means you can continue using iptables for the next $planned_lifetime_of_nftables years.